# play local video file on a web browser

Tags: html, file, video, local

Okay, I have video files on my network drive which I would like to play on my website, only pc's connected to my network and visit my site will see the files.

So I am trying to use videojs.com to get this working...

If I enter a video file that is hosted online it will play it, entering

```
file://mybooklive/Public/Shared%20Movies/Anchorman%20(2004).mp4
```

it will not play (even though typing that into chrome's URL bar will play the video).

So basically this WILL play a online video...

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  
preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"  
data-setup="{}">  
<source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" 
type='video/mp4'> </video>
```

and this will not play (local file)

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  
preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"  
data-setup="{}">  
<source src="file://mybooklive/Public/Shared%20Movies/Anchorman%20(2004).mp4" 
type='video/mp4'> </video>
```

Please help!!!

I'm using MyBookLive so I don't think I can enter an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to play using your file path, you will need to use the Internet URL absolute path
Please change your code, so that the file will be available through URL, and not file system

Using this model, you can place your files anywhere, as long as you point the correct URL to them

Read more about [video.js documentation and starting up here](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/stable/docs/guides/setup.md)

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  
preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"  
data-setup="{}">  
<source src="http://path-to-your-website/Shared%20Movies/Anchorman%20(2004).mp4" 
type='video/mp4'> </video>
```

Read more about it [here](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/a/absopath.htm)

If you don't want to use an absolute path, [you can use a relative path](http://webdesign.about.com/od/beginningtutorials/a/aa040502a.htm), based on where your script is :

```
<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls  
preload="auto" width="640" height="264" poster="my_video_poster.png"  
data-setup="{}">  
<source src="relative-path-to-your-mp4/Anchorman%20(2004).mp4" 
type='video/mp4'> </video>
```

Comment: Thanks for a reply. My problem is that I can't install wordpress on the mybooklive, so the site needs to be hosted online, and the video files are 4GB each. (Over 300GB in total) so I can't upload them online (Not with the internet speed here.) So is there any way of getting a site to play a local file?

Comment: Can you create a URL link with MyBookLive to your videos, which you can download from anywhere ? How you access your drive from the internet ? (i.e. you are not from home ) ?

Comment: With the mybooklive you have to go to wd2go.com and then login to access files.

Comment: and it doesn't have a "create link" for each video ?

Comment: No just an "open in explorer" button?

Answer (score 0):

No need for `file://` Put your video in the same folder as your html fime and use,

```
<video width="640" height="264" controls>
  <source src="filename.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Then you have to give hyperlink to the file in your site.